# Looking for equivalent Windsor Castle's features in Autofac

Tags: autofac

I have been been Windsor Castle IoC container for the last 3 years; I am trying to put together a proof of concept using Autofac and is having trouble finding equivalent Windsor's Castle's features in Autofac.

• In Windsor Castle's IWinsorContainer API, there is a Release method that allow immediate release of a component instance. Is there an equivalent method in Autofac container?

• Windsor Castle has a concept of “pooled” lifestyle, please see the link below. Is there an equivalent in Autofac?
http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/manual/coretypedocs/Generated_PooledAttribute.html

• Windsor Castle’s DynamicProxy provide a way to do method interception. I found the link below and followed Nicholas’s instruction but I am not able to find the IInterceptor interface in AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2 or the source code that he mentioned. 
http://nblumhardt.com/archives/aop-with-autofac-and-dynamicproxy2/

I would appreciate any information you could provide!

Answer (score 4):

**There is no explicit Release in Autofac.** Component lifetimes in Autofac are managed by lifetime scopes. The closest you could probably get to explicit release of an object is to make use of [the IDisposable support](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DeterministicDisposal) inherent in lifetime scopes.

Say you have a class that implements IDisposable and you register it:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<SomeComponent>().As<IMyDependency>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
var container = builder.Build();
```

If you create a lifetime scope from which to resolve the component, then when the lifetime scope is disposed, so is your component:

```
using(var lifetime = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  var myThing = lifetime.Resolve<IMyDependency>();
  // myThing.Dispose() gets called at the end of the using
}
```

Alternatively, you may look into [owned instances](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OwnedInstances), where you control when IDisposable.Dispose() gets called.

**There is no equivalent of the Pooled lifetime in Autofac.** You have your choice of...

- Per Dependency: Create a new instance each time the component is resolved.
- Per Lifetime Scope: Create a new instance once for each owning lifetime scope (like you saw in the above example).
- Single Instance: Just create one.

There's a wiki article about [the lifetime scopes available here](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope).

You could probably do some custom coding to get pooling to work involving creation of a custom IComponentLifetime implementation and an extension to IRegistrationBuilder so you could do something like...

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>().PooledLifetime(32);
```

...but I don't think it'll be a one-or-two-line thing. If you do end up creating it, consider contributing back to AutofacContrib.

**The IInterceptor interface is in Castle.Core.dll** - Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor - not in AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2.